# sync facebook friends birthdays with my android app

Tags: android, android-facebook

I am writing an calendar app in which, I am fetching list of all my Facebook friends with their Name, DOB and Profile Picture into my calendar. How can i get all these. please help me.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you do any research? What have you come up with?

Comment: up to now i developed calendar, now am trying to add facebook friends b'days to the calendar( sync with facebook). so could you please provide some information how to sync with fb and give me some sort of links to get idea on it.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first create object and veriable for facebook:

```
private static String FACEBOOK_APP_ID = "492429660800628";
private Facebook facebook;
private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
```

after OnCreate Method :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_screen);

    facebook = new Facebook(FACEBOOK_APP_ID);
    mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);

    loginFacebook();//this method when called when you required..

}



private void loginFacebook() {

    if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {

        facebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "email", "publish_stream",
                "read_stream" }, new LoginDialogListener());

    } else {

        getProfileInformation();

    }

}



class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {

    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        try {

            getProfileInformation();

        } catch (Exception error) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, error.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
                "Something went wrong. Please try again.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onError(DialogError error) {
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
                "Something went wrong. Please try again.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onCancel() {
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
                "Something went wrong. Please try again.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

please try this method after login facebook:

```
public void getProfileInformation() {


    try {

        JSONObject profile = Util.parseJson(facebook.request("me"));
        Log.e("Profile", "" + profile);

        mUserId = profile.getString("id");
        mUserToken = facebook.getAccessToken();
        mUserName = profile.getString("name");
        mUserEmail = profile.getString("email");

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                Log.e("FaceBook_Profile",""+mUserId+"\n"+mUserToken+"\n"+mUserName+"\n"+mUserEmail);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Name: " + mUserName + "\nEmail: " + mUserEmail,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



            }

        });

    } catch (FacebookError e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

using latest facebook android SDK
from [developer.facebook link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/fetch-user-data/)https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/fetch-user-data/

Comment: how to use facebook json data in my app coding.?
 from which url we can access json data.?

Comment: Thanks you @KiranMane. how it stores the fb b'day events on same date in my calendar app.?

Comment: Hello @KiranMane am getting NullPointerExp and ClassNotFoundExps at compile time, i can't able to find the solution.if You don't mind Could you please send me the total code to mail id(rakhi191@gmail.com).Thanks